# Angular2 Githhub-Pages Deployment hangs on Loading

Tags: git, angular, github-pages

I am using angular-cli to deploy to gh-pages.

When I run `ng serve` it serves the app, no problem.

Ran `ng github-pages:deploy` on master branch, no errors.

Go to https://mbowen13.github.io/Github-search/ and the app hangs on Loading...

Here is a link to the [repo](https://github.com/mbowen13/Github-search).

Comment: you get 404 errors for scripts. Are you sure you're deploying them as well?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Thanks. Not sure why it can find the scripts when using `ng serve` but then can't find those scripts after deploying to gh-pages.